# Missing type definition information in VS Code when own Node.js package is published on NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, jsdoc

I cannot figure out why, once my own [`efficy-enterprise-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/efficy-enterprise-api) NPM package is published, the type definitions (used by VS Code intellisense) are not available anymore compared to locally referencing the package, e.g. `import { CrmRpc} from "../efficy-enterprise-api";`

Package is written in native ES6 (using .mjs extension) with JSDoc annotations.

No issue when locally referencing the Node.js package:

```js
import { CrmRpc } from "../efficy-enterprise-api";

const crm = new CrmRpc(); // Type definition CrmRpc is accessible
const Cont = crm.openEditObject("Cont", 0); // Type definition "EditObject" is accessible
```

Missing type definitions when referencing the published package:

```js
import { CrmRpc} from "efficy-enterprise-api";

const crm = new CrmRpc(); // Type definition CrmRpc is accessible
const Cont = crm.openEditObject("Cont", 0); // Type definition "EditObject" is not accessible anymore...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deduced the issue to the usage of the separated `./@typings` folder for the generate `.mts` and `.mts.map` files. I was unable to find a functional configuration of package.json to point to these multiple generated files (not only `index.mjs`)

By running typescript tsc **without** `outDir=@typings` configured, the typings are fully functional.